# Secret initialization from Blob storage failed due to missing both an Azure Storage connection string and a SAS connection uri

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am getting this error while configuring blob output binding for Azure function HTTP trigger in Visual Studio. I tried assigning value in the `host.json` file but still got this error.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: Secret initialization from Blob storage failed due to missing both an Azure Storage connection string and a SAS connection URI. For Blob Storage, please provide at least one of these. If you intend to use files for secrets, add an App Setting key 'AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType' with the value 'Files'.

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,

  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=.......",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "f...........",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~2",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "8.11.1",
    "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES": "*",
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": "1"
  },
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

Can anyone please help me with configuring blob output bindings for azure functions in visual studio?

Comment: This started happening to me as well on my local machine after updating the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage NuGet package from 4.0.5 to 5.0.0.

Comment: I can confirm, this happened to me too when using 5.0.0. Downgrade to 4.0.5 and it will work

Comment: I had to downgrade as well the Microsoft.Extensions.Azure NuGet package from 1.1.1 to 1.0.0.

Comment: I had this problem today on a new Azure Functions project (.NET 7 Isolated) and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` was not installed on NuGet packages. After I install version 5.1.1 it worked.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, local.settings.json was added with correct values but it wasn't in the .csproj file:

Adding this in one of "itemgroup" tags helped:

```
<None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```

BTW local settings JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": Your_Connection_String,
    "ServiceBusConnection": Your_Connection_String

  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in addition to reverting the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` package to version 4.0.5 I needed to set the `AzureWebJobsStorage` to use the connection string.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue moving from 3.1 to 6.0. I must have lost the AzureWebJobsStorage entry in my json file along the way and MS must have made the connection mandatory. I opened a new Function App and used the default values in my old codes settings an it worked. I have not got far enough to know if I will need some connection in the cloud yet, but I will find out soon

"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
}

Answer (score 3):

Downgrade **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage** NuGet Package from 5.0.0. to 4.0.5

Comment: This solved my issue, but then I reverted back to version 5 and the error was gone...

Answer (score 2):

This error message may also appear if your AzureWebJobsStorage variable has an empty value in local.settings.json. This occurred in my Node.js function app.